# Can I improve the performance of this MySQL query by adding an index?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

I ran SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON'; in MySQL and this appeared in the log:

```
SELECT U.*, DATE_FORMAT(U.TIMESTAMP_X, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') TIMESTAMP_X, 
IF(U.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 120 SECOND), 'Y', 'N') IS_ONLINE, 
DATE_FORMAT(U.DATE_REGISTER, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') DATE_REGISTER, 
DATE_FORMAT(U.LAST_LOGIN, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') LAST_LOGIN, 
DATE_FORMAT(U.PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY, '%d.%m.%Y') PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY  
FROM b_user U 
WHERE (1=1 AND (((upper(U.EMAIL) like upper('%uggjplove13@gmail.com%') and U.EMAIL is not null)))) ORDER BY U.ID ASC;
```

Can I add an index for this query to make it run faster?

explain

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | U     | index | ix_b_user_email,email_id | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 105308 | Using where |
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `b_user` (
  `ID` int(18) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TIMESTAMP_X` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `LOGIN` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CHECKWORD` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIVE` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `NAME` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_LOGIN` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_REGISTER` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LID` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_PROFESSION` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_WWW` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_ICQ` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_GENDER` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_BIRTHDATE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_PHOTO` int(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_PHONE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_FAX` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_MOBILE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_PAGER` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_STREET` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `PERSONAL_MAILBOX` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_CITY` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_STATE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_ZIP` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_COUNTRY` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_NOTES` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `WORK_COMPANY` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_DEPARTMENT` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_POSITION` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_WWW` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_PHONE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_FAX` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_PAGER` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_STREET` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `WORK_MAILBOX` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_CITY` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_STATE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_ZIP` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_COUNTRY` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_PROFILE` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `WORK_LOGO` int(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORK_NOTES` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ADMIN_NOTES` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `STORED_HASH` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `XML_ID` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXTERNAL_AUTH_ID` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHECKWORD_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SECOND_NAME` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONFIRM_CODE` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` int(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTO_TIME_ZONE` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_ZONE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_ZONE_OFFSET` int(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITLE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `BX_USER_ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LANGUAGE_ID` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_login` (`LOGIN`,`EXTERNAL_AUTH_ID`),
  KEY `ix_b_user_email` (`EMAIL`),
  KEY `ix_b_user_activity_date` (`LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE`),
  KEY `IX_B_USER_XML_ID` (`XML_ID`),
  KEY `bdate` (`PERSONAL_BIRTHDATE`),
  KEY `dregister` (`DATE_REGISTER`),
  KEY `email_id` (`EMAIL`,`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=109606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: `upper(U.EMAIL) like upper('%uggjplove13@gmail.com%')` - do you need to do this? As you use `utf8_unicode_ci` the `upper()` part should not be needed, the "ci" stands for "case insensitive". But do you really need LIKE with % at the beginning? - that one has not way to use index.

Comment: `1=1` and `email is not null` is redundant. So I think the query is created automatically by an application. And this application puts a '%' at the beginning and the end of the search string.

Comment: yes. this is CMS bitrix.

Comment: thanks. I understood. it is necessary to tell php developers to alter the code

Comment: Thats the best way in this case. For current query index on `(ID, EMAIL)` might help with newer mysql, but only a bit (the table is quite wide, so full index scan is better than full table scan in this case). Note: your index `email_id` is redundant - `ix_b_user_email` works the same because in InnoDB primary key is appended to each secondary index.

Answer (score 2):

Can you get rid of the leading `%` in '%uggjplove13@gmail.com%'?  If so, that will make a world of difference!  Any index starting with `EMAIL` can be used (assuming you get rid of `upper`), and the query will be fast.

If not, read on...

`FULLTEXT(email)`, when it can be used, will be very fast.  But you may have to build some intelligence into when to use it, and when to resort to `LIKE '%...%'`.  For example, `uggjplove13@gmail.com` --> `MATCH(email) AGAINST('+uggjplove13 +gmail' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`, but skip the `com` since it will be ignored anyway.  But...  `xi.li@ab.com` cannot use `FULLTEXT` unless you crank down the min_word_len to 2 (which makes the index much bigger).

(Yes, get rid of the `UPPER()` calls.)

Remove most of the `WORK_*` and `PERSONAL_*` columns and build a table of `Locations` with those columns (one set, not two sets).  Then have `WORK_LOCATION` and `PERSONAL_LOCATION` as ids in your table.  This will clean up the schema (some), and will help in various minor ways.

The `ORDER BY id` does not hurt much since there are (probably) very few rows to sort after the `WHERE` is finished.  But then, what is significant about the `ID` order?  However, the excessive use of `(255)` hurts the sort, since it turns into `CHAR(255)` (765-bytes) during the sort.  Change the `VARCHAR` limits to realistic values.  Also...

`SELECT * ...`, or even `SELECT WORK_NOTES ...` slows things down because of the `TEXT` field.  `ORDER BY` would prefer to do the sorting in RAM, but when it sees `TEXT`, it punts and builds a tmp MyISAM table; this is slower.  This leads to the admonition of not using `SELECT *`, especially when you are looking for only non-TEXT columns.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is NO, you cannot improve this with just an index creation. You should:

- Replace U.* with only the columns you want in your recordset;
- Shift all the formatting and conversion processing effort into the application code;
- Create a full text index on the EMAIL column and rewrite the query to use it.

The relevant documentation on Full Text Indexes, for MySQL 5.6, can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Keep in mind the above comments as they are also quite valid.

Comment: I am not sure you can use fulltext index to search emails (the @ sign etc) but it might return few enough rows to make the LIKE viable.

Comment: That situation does not appear to be a restriction: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html 

Nevertheless, mind that "The '%' character is not a supported wildcard character for full-text searches."

Comment: I don't see how a full text search will help here. And even if it does, the answer does not provide how the query should be rewritten with `MATCH`.

Comment: Also, consider removing the order by ID if it's not relevant as it adds processing load on the database server since it will sort the records before returning the result.